# Get a tuple from a list of tuple if the element occurs in a list of string

Tags: python, list

Hi I am working on a data transforming project. I have a `List` of `tuples`:

```
A = [("someThing",0),("someThingOnce",1),("someThingTwice",2)]
```

and an another list of string:

```
B = ["something","somethingonce","somethingagain"]
```

Now what I want to do is, I want the elements from `list A` that are present in `list B`.

The desired output is:

```
C = [("someThing",0),("someThingOnce",1)]
```

How can I achieve this in an optimised way since, `list B` has `7000` elements while `list A` has at max 20 elements.

I can't use `numpy` as the lists aren't of the same type, i..e B might contain numbers as well.

The tuple[0] in `list A` elements might repeat as well.

Comment: `b = set(B); result = [a for a in A if a[0].lower() in b]`

Comment: are their repeated elements in list as well?

Comment: @NimishBansal there is a possibility that words might repeat.

Comment: but the tuple doesn't right?

Comment: @NimishBansal they might as well. But the tuple[1] would not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `list-comprehension` is the most efficient solution for this (if `A` has less elements than `B`).

```
>>> A = [("someThing",0),("someThingOnce",1),("someThingTwice",2)]
>>> B = ["something","somethingonce","somethingagain"]
>>> C = [(i, j) for i, j in A if i.lower() in B]
>>> C
[('someThing', 0), ('someThingOnce', 1)]
```

Comment: this is the exact opposite of "optimized," and list comprehensions per se have nothing to do with efficiency, but with 7000… who cares.

Comment: @hop What would you suggest then? I think this is `O(n^2)` at the moment...though with only 7000 it doesn't really matter

Comment: @hop Ahh, good point, I skipped over the part about the repeats! Will add to the answer :)

Comment: @JoeIddon it was working before but when I converted the list to a set, like you have, it stopped working

Comment: @iam.Carrot My bad, I made a mistake (`b` != `B`) ! But I have corrected it now, and can confirm that it does work :)

Comment: @JoeIddon I used it in `C = [(i, j) for i, j in A if i.lower() in set(B)]` manner, it doesn't work. am I missing something?

Comment: @JoeIddon No errors, just that the C is an empty list

Comment: @iam.Carrot If you copy the exact code in the answer now into a terminal, it *will* run, I just checked!

Comment: @JoeIddon Can you please tell me how is it different? I can't seem to make out

Comment: @iam.Carrot Your code is only different in that you put `set(B)` straight into the `comp` rather than using an intermediary variable, but that shouldn't matter. Have you tried copying the code in the answer exactly?

Comment: @JoeIddon Yes I did try it. It doesn't seem to work. It's the same thing, no errors but the list is empty

Comment: @iam.Carrot I am sorry as stuck for suggestions... different version of Python maybe?

Comment: @JoeIddon I've marked it as an answer, can you revert back the changes that you had done for that set thing. I'll write up a logic to handle the duplicity. The silver lining is, it gives me multiple matches from A.